# Can’t login to /wp-admin area with correct username and password

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I tried a lot to reset password but it's not sending a link to email, it's not showing the wrong password. I tried each and every possible solution that I saw on StackOverflow like htacess file change, database user details update and other but nothing work for me.

Comment: Have you tried temporarily renaming the plugins folder in case something is interfering?

Comment: And when you did DB details update, did you have a hash of localhost password with same setup, to paste into the users password field?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to .htaccess file, I assume that you have access to site via FTP. Find your theme folder (/wp-content/themes/current_theme_name) and find `functions.php` file. If you can't find that file, you are probably not in the theme folder. However, if you are absolutely sure, you may create that file. Then edit `functions.php` and add this code:

```
$user_id = wp_create_user( 'new_user_name', 'new_user_password', 'this@is.my.mail' );
$wp_user_object = new WP_User( $user_id );
$wp_user_object->set_role('administrator');
```

This code will add new 'new_user_name' user. Of course you need to change name and password for your own security. And please make sure that you are using unique name and email for new user. After that, refresh your page. New user should be created and you may delete this code from your `functions.php` file.

Provided according to [how to add user programmatically](https://lukasznowicki.info/how-to-add-wordpress-administrator-using-php/).